# Is it possible to insert animated emoji into the sending text using the Telegram Api?

Tags: animation, telegram, emoji

Telegram has a premium subscription that allows you to write a message and add to the text (important! not separately, like stickers, but specifically to the text). Is it possible to do something similar with the Telegram API?

I looked in the documentation and found only https://core.telegram.org/api/animated-emojis#emoji-reactions, there were animated reactions to messages, sending animated emoji like stickers, but not what I seem to need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animated emoji are a "premium" feature of Telegram and so far bots can't use them. The documentation that you linked is part of the "Telegram API", i.e. the API that user clients like your mobile Telegram app use. The documentation of the Telegram *Bot* API is here: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api. It does not indicate in any way that bots are able to use the emoji.

See also [Telegram API Custom Emoji sending in message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361532).